# XSLT: Splitting a string and doing something with each character

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm an XSLT newbie. I've gone through the tutorials and I've been able to do about 80% of what I want, with my XML document. However, I am stuck on something. In my XML document, I have attributes that consist of values like "ERA", "EDA", "EDAR", and so on. Essentially these attributes consist of combinations of the letters E, D, A, and R. The E, D, A, and R map to *Edit*, *Delete*, *Add*, and *Read*.

If I was doing this imperatively, I would split the string into its component characters and then check each character to see if I should output *Edit*, *Delete*, *Add*, or *Read*. How can I do something similar in XSLT? I was thinking of using the length and substring functions and making a loop of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline (or external) map:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:local="http://localhost">
    <local:map letter="E" text="Edit"/>
    <local:map letter="D" text="Delete"/>
    <local:map letter="A" text="Add"/>
    <local:map letter="R" text="Read"/>
    <xsl:template match="test">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates
             select="document('')/*/local:map[
                        contains(current(),@letter)
                     ]/@text"
             mode="sequence"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="sequence">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(' ', 1 div (position()!=1)),.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<test>Edit Delete Add Read</test>
```

Sequence of `xsl:if` instructions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="test">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="contains(.,'E')">Edit </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(.,'D')">Delete </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(.,'A')">Add </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(.,'R')">Read </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<test>Edit Delete Add Read </test>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the attribute contains only E D A and R (or you don't care about other possible values), a simple set of `contains(@attr,...)` in an `<xsl:choose...>` should work fine:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains(@attr,'A')">
    ...
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(@attr,'D')">
    ...
  </xsl:when>
  etc...
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Yes, it will only contain E, D, A, R. This seems like a much easier method!

Comment: @Alejandro, will it test it against every `<xsl:when>`? Or does it break out of the `<xsl:choose>` when one of the clauses match?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using a recursive function/template:

```
<xsl:template name="translateAccessModes">

 <xsl:param name="accessModes" />

 <xsl:if test="string-length($accessModes) > 0">

  <xsl:variable name="accessMode" select="substring($accessModes, 1, 1)" />
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$accessMode='E'">Edit </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="$accessMode='D'">Delete </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="$accessMode='A'">Add </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="$accessMode='R'">Read </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>Unrecognized Access Mode: <xsl:value-of select="$accessMode" /> </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

  <xsl:call-template name="translateAccessModes">
   <xsl:with-param name="accessModes" select="substring($accessModes, 2, string-length($accessModes))" />
  </xsl:call-template>

 </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Not sure if this is the best way of doing it, though.